# JavaScript sort with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

In my movies array with reduce function I'm trying to make genre of the book an id and if the book has more than one genre the first one should be used as id. The code I wrote is not working the way it should. What is wrong with my code and how can I make it work the correct way

```
const movies = [
    {
        title: 'Harry Potter',
        genre: 'fantasy'
    },
    {
        title:'Bridgerton',
        genre:'romance'
    },
    {
        title: 'Chesnut Man',
        genre: 'crime'
    },
    {
        title: 'Little Women',
        genre: 'romance'
    },
    {
        title:'The Mask',
        genre: 'comedy'

    },
    {
        title:'Holidate',
        genre: ['comedy', 'romance']

    }]
```

`

```
/*

//correct output
{
  fantasy: { title: 'Harry Potter', genre: 'fantasy' },
  romance: {{ title: 'Little Women', genre: 'romance' },{ title: 'Holidate', genre: 'romance' },}}
  crime: { title: 'Chesnut Man', genre: 'crime' },
  comedy: {{ title: 'The Mask', genre: 'comedy'},{ title: 'Holidate', genre: 'comedy' } }
}

*/

// my code

const genreSort = movies.reduce(function(acc, curBook){
    if(Array.isArray(curBook.genre)){
        return {...acc,[curBook.genre[0]]:curBook}
    }
    else if(curBook.genre){
        return {...acc,[curBook.genre]:curBook}
        
    }
    return acc
    
},{})
console.log(genreSort)
```

`

Comment: Object property order is not something you should rely on.

Comment: _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: The use of the word "sort" is part of the problem here, I think.

Comment: Your expectation doesn't seem correct, if you have this output then maybe that works for you:

`{ fantasy: ['Harry Potter'], romance: ['Little Women','Holidate'], crime: ['Chesnut Man'], comedy: ['The Mask','Holidate'] }`

Answer (score 0):

You;re overwriting your single element for each group every time. You need an array there.

```js
const movies = [{
        title: 'Harry Potter',
        genre: 'fantasy'
    },{
        title:'Bridgerton',
        genre:'romance'
    },{
        title: 'Chesnut Man',
        genre: 'crime'
    },{
        title: 'Little Women',
        genre: 'romance'
    },{
        title:'The Mask',
        genre: 'comedy'
    },{
        title:'Holidate',
        genre: ['comedy', 'romance']

    }];

const genreSort = movies.reduce(function(acc, curBook){
    let key = Array.isArray(curBook.genre) ? curBook.genre[0] : curBook.genre
    var arr = acc[key] || []
    arr.push(curBook);
    acc[key] = arr;
    return acc
    
},{})
console.log(genreSort)
```